# saving output in a file using COBOL language

Tags: cobol

I need help writing a small program in COBOL.
I wrote this piece of code:

```cobol
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. CallC.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 INITBUF PIC X(10).
01 SHOWBUF PIC X(10).
01 BUF USAGE IS POINTER.
01 NUM PIC 9(10). 
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MOVE 10 to NUM.
CALL "getBuffer" USING BY VALUE NUM RETURNING BUF.
CALL "initBuffer" USING BY VALUE BUF RETURNING INITBUF.
CALL "showBuffer" USING BY VALUE BUF RETURNING SHOWBUF.
DISPLAY SHOWBUF.
STOP RUN.
```

How do I go about writing the `DISPLAY` result to a file?

Comment: In the usual way. Redirect the output to a file. Details depend on your OS, but it's easy to search-engine for.

Comment: This URL https://rosettacode.org/wiki/File_input/output has helped me

Comment: Well, do you mind indicating how?

Answer (score 1):

Bill. Declare the file as in the example below. Move whatever you want to output into the output variable then Write outputVar

```
 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                            
 CONFIGURATION SECTION.                           
 INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                            
 FILE-CONTROL.                                    
    SELECT PARM-OUT              ASSIGN TO PARMOUT.
*************************************************
 DATA DIVISION.                                   
 FILE SECTION.                                    

 FD  PARM-OUT                                      
  RECORDING MODE F.                            

 01  PARMIN-REC.                                  
     05  PSID-IN          PIC 9(09).              
     05  PCID-IN          PIC 9(08).              
     05  IN-PCIDSEQ       PIC 9(03).
```

Comment: Is that Bill me? If yes, why? How would what you have shown affect a DISPLAY statement? Where is outputVar?

Comment: Ok. Thank's for your suggestions. Where can I test my code in Windows environment ? Is it impossible in Windows ?

Comment: @Snorri as suggested before, "windows output redirection". The code provided is OS-independent. It won't do what you want on any OS.

Comment: @BillWoodger, thank you for good answer. How I should rewrite 
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                            
CONFIGURATION SECTION.
for Windows and any Linux OS ?

Comment: @Snorri you should be able to find lots of examples with the ASSIGN hard-coded to a file-name. You may find other examples. In general this won't affect DISPLAY. Are you rather saying you want the output always to go to a file, using OPEN and WRITE and CLOSE?